# Get rows with matching values in column in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, join, inner-join

I have the following DDLs...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `id_product` int(10),
  `id_manufacturer` int(10)
  );


INSERT INTO `product` (`id_product`, `id_manufacturer`) VALUES
(1,1),
(2,1),
(3,2),
(4,1),
(5,2);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `feature_product` (
  `id_feature` int(10),
  `id_product` int(10),
  `id_feature_value` int(10)
);


INSERT INTO `feature_product` (`id_feature`, `id_product`, `id_feature_value`) VALUES
(5, 1, 9),
(5, 2, 9),
(5, 3, 10),
(5, 4, 10),
(7, 5, 10);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbe05/1/0

Can you explain me please, how I can get - all Products with the same Manufacturer and the same Feature_value?

Now (in project) I do it with 2 additional SELECT's (for getting id_manufacturer and id_feature_value), but maybe there are more correct (and fast) way?

Thanks for your time and sorry for my English)

I need too see result like this:

```
id_product | 
-----------|
1          |
2          |
```

only this 2 products have same manufacturer and (at the same time) same feature value

Comment: What woud the desired result look like?

Comment: added,and thanks for your help with editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use GROUP_CONCAT:

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p.id_product SEPARATOR '\n') AS Products 
FROM product p 
INNER JOIN feature_product fp ON (p.id_product = fp.id_product AND fp.id_feature = 5) 
GROUP BY p.id_manufacturer, fp.id_feature_value
HAVING COUNT(p.id_manufacturer) > 1
AND COUNT(fp.id_feature_value)>1;`

This will give you the list of Products having multiple Manufacturer Id and Feature Value in a single line, separated by a newline character. You can change the separator as your requirement.

Here is the SQL Fiddle link:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbe05/70

Comment: I supplemented the question, maybe I provided bad explanations first time, thanks for your reply

Comment: Is it ok if you get your output in one row separated by a delimiter instead of getting it in two different rows?

Comment: ...course I can "explode" result in php. So, imposible to get result in 2 different rows?

Comment: Two rows seems tough.. I can give you a result separated by a newline character in one single row.

Comment: heh, befre add this question I read docs/examples with - group by, having, count - but did not understand how to apply them in my case. Many thanks for your answer, it's very good solution and I'll go study mysql documentation more deeply

Comment: So is this solving your problem?